# Do not download all Maven dependencies on a Docker build

Tags: maven, docker

I'm trying to create a Dockerfile to then build a Maven project.

I wonder how to fix the Dockerfile and what command to then execute.

I would like to know how to run the build so that it does NOT download all the Maven dependencies every time it builds when the source code, sitting in the src/ directory, has NOT changed.

Here is my Dockerfile file:

```
FROM maven:3.3.9-jdk-8

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN cd /usr/src/app

ADD pom.xml /usr/src/app

RUN mvn dependency:resolve

ADD src /usr/src/app

RUN mvn package

ENTRYPOINT ["mvn"]
CMD ["package"]
```

Should I run the `docker run --rm -it toolbox` command or the `docker build -t toolbox .` command ?

Both of these above commands run fine, except that they both download all the Maven dependencies even if the source code has not been touched.

Comment: You may want to work through some more basic Docker tasks to get a better understanding of how it works. If you set it up properly, you can, in fact, get it to "skip" steps where the data hasn't changed by using the Docker build cache. see http://thenewstack.io/understanding-the-docker-cache-for-faster-builds/ and https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/ Also, do you mean to run `mvn package` both in the build and when the container starts?

Comment: No I don't mean to run the `mvn package` twice in fact. I thought I had to after I added the src to the app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's how Docker works. Every time you do `docker run`, it creates a new container which does not have any access to the files in the old container. So, it download all dependencies it requires. You can circumvent this by declaring an external volume. Looking at the `Dockerfile` of Maven, it declares a volume `/root/.m2`. So, you can use a directory in your host machine and attach it to this volume by `-v` option. Your Docker command would be,

```
`docker run -v <directory-in-your-host>:/root/.m2 <other-options-and-commands>
```

Every time you run a new `docker run`, Maven will look into your local directory before downloading the dependency.

However, my question is why don't you build your app first and use the resulting jar to create the docker images unless you have any specific reasons. You can create your own Dockerfile using java base image or simply use one of the `docker-maven-plugin` like [spotify](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin) available out there. That makes your life a lot easier.

Comment: I tried the `docker run -v /home/stephane/.m2:/root/.m2 --rm -it toolbox`command. But it does not compile my edited source code file. Maven says: No sources to compile. Is it what you tried telling me to do ? Should I still run the docker build command before ? To answer your second question, I'm learning Docker and trying to build with it for learning purpose. My next Docker try will be to build with Maven (and not Docker) but to use Docker in the build to run the integration tests in a Docker container.

Comment: I notice I was doing a `RUN mvn clean install` to build the app when building the container, and also doing a `ENTRYPOINT ["mvn"]
CMD ["package"]`which also builds the app, when running the container. I only want to build the app, that is, create its jar archive file. I wonder if I can just build the container and never run it.. if that makes sense ?

Comment: If I should be building my app and then using it for a docker image, what is the purpose of a docker maven image? Just wondering?